# RegularExperssion with text sections and including Polish letters

Tags: regex, data-annotations

I would like to create a regular expression which have the following structure

```
text(length from 5 to 15)+text(length from 5 to 15)+text(length from 5 to 15)
```

The last section of text is not mandatory. In each section lower and uppercase are allowed. Additional I would like to include Polish letters like {ą,ś,ź}.
So far I have created that expression but the validation shows me wrong given input.

```
[RegularExpression("^[A-Za-z]{5-15}+[A-Za-z]{5-15}+([A-Za-z]{5-15})?")]
```

Comment: Are you validating the string on the server or client or *both* sides?

Comment: I'm validating the string on both sides.

Comment: So, you cannot use `\p{L}`. Can you please provide at least 1 valid string to test against? I am not quite sure: are the `+` symbols literal plus symbols there?

Comment: This in an example which I want add Śniadanie+Obiadokolacja

Comment: So, the pattern is: a word from 5 to 15 letters, then 0 to 2 sequences of 5 to 15 letters.

Comment: Yes, eventually third optional sequence, between each sequence must be included sign "+".

Comment: Glad my answer worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)) since you reached 15 rep points and are now entitled to upvoting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are validating both at the client *and* server sides, you cannot use .NET `\p{L}` (any Unicode letter) regex construct. You need to explicitly list the English and Polish letters in the regex.

Use

```
^[a-zA-ZąćęłńóśźżĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŹŻ]{5,15}(?:\+[a-zA-ZąćęłńóśźżĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŹŻ]{5,15}){0,2}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wW9P0f/1)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-zA-ZąćęłńóśźżĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŹŻ]{5,15}` - 5 to 15 English and Polish letters
- `(?:\+[a-zA-ZąćęłńóśźżĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŹŻ]{5,15}){0,2}` - 0 to 2 (`{0,2}`) sequences of:

  - `\+` - a literal plus symbols (must be escaped, or use `[+]` to avoid escaping issues)
  - `[a-zA-ZąćęłńóśźżĄĆĘŁŃÓŚŹŻ]{5,15}` - 5 to 15 English and Polish letters
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

does this work for you

```
/(\p{L}{5,15}\+){2}(\p{L}{5,15})/
```

**\p{L}** matches any kind of letter from any language
{5-15} matches the characters {5-15} literally (case sensitive) 
**{2}** Quantifier — Matches 2 times 
**+** matches "+" exactly

this matches the string "ABCDE+ABCDE+abcde"

Comment: How abouts sign "+" between each section?

Comment: is that the sign "+" or string concatenation ?

Comment: I can update the regex if + is part of the string to be matched

Comment: "+" is just sign that must be included in pattern.